# How to run applet without jre7?

Tags: applet, java

I require jre7 to run an applet which is posted by some site, on the other hand i require java6 on my machine so that my hadoop commands should work. I cannot upgrade from java6 to java7. And I cannot install jre7 unless i have java7 on my machine. What should i do?

Comment: run a minimal vm for your hadoop commands.

Comment: You don't need Java6.

Answer (score 2):

You can install both Java 6 and Java 7 side by side.  Since you apparently need both, that is one option.

It is also highly likely that Hadoop will work with Java 7 as well as Java 6:

- Java 7 is designed to be backwards compatible with earlier Java releases.
- It is highly likely that any (hypothetical) compatibility issues with Hadoop on Java 7 were fixed a long time ago.)

So a second option would be to simply upgrade to Java 7, and then uninstall Java 6 to save disc space.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove openjdk

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

To install java 7 run the following code

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

Comment: You are making a LOT of assumptions in this answer; e.g. 1) that he is using Ubuntu rather than Windows or (say) RHEL, 2) that he previously had installed OpenJDK 6.0 (not the Oracle version) and 3) that he *wants* to use apt-get to install rather than an Oracle installer.